# SSDT - specify authorization user on schema create

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

I have a `sqlproj` XML for Azure SQL Database. I want to deploy database with several tables into specific schema which is also created using this build. How to specify what user should be used for `CREATE SCHEMA [schema-name] AUTHORIZATION [user]` ? By default it uses user `dbo` but I need to change it. How to specify it in the `sqlproj`?

Comment: Can't you find the `CREATE SCHEMA` code in the SSDT project and add the desired `AUTHORIZATION` onto the end of it?

Comment: I cannot - when I do that I get `Error SQL71501: Schema: [schemaName] has an unresolved reference to object [user-name].`

Comment: You need to add the user to the project too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared the user (service principal) trying to deploy the solution to SQL Database was not set as an AAD admin on the SQL server. It seems a little bit strange to me, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking in a wrong place. All database schema definitions in SSDT, by default, are placed into the `Security` folder. In it, you will have your `schema-name.sql` file, and there you can adjust the `authorization` clause.

For the project to build, the owner of that schema should also be present in the project. Most likely, you will find it in the same folder.

Comment: I do not have `Security` folder in my project, but I have a `schema-name.sql`. In the same level I should have also the `CREATE USER` ? Or?

Comment: @romanzdk, it doesn't actually matter where script files are located in SSDT. The `Security` folder is a default location where SSDT puts schemas, users, permissions etc. by default if you create your project by reverse-engineering an existing database. You can put your user definition anywhere, but it's better to maintain at least some semblance of order. That, and it's pretty pointless trying to fight against SSDT's defaults.